# PHP - foreach loop WITH a condition without additional internal IF statement

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, foreach

*I understand that pdo/mysqli is the required standard, for the time being I have no choice other than to use msql*

Currently I have this setup to loop through results and display them accordingly

```
foreach($Items as $Item)
{
    if($Item["Col1"] == "valueFoo"){
        echo "<li>display relevant results</li>";                   
    }
}
```

Is there way I can do this without looping through the whole array if `Items` and instead combining the foreach loop with a condition. Alternatively filtering the array prior to the `foreachloop`? What is the most efficient?

Currently I have 60 items and display them in lists like as below

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL";
$Data = mysql_query($SQL, $db);

$Items = array();
    while ($NewRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($Data)) {
    // Append all rows to an array
    $Items[] = $NewRow;
}

echo "<ul>";
foreach($Items as $Item)
    {
        if($Item["Col1"] == "valueFoo"){
            echo "<li>display relevant results</li>";                   
        }
    } 
echo "</ul>";
echo "<ul>";
foreach($Items as $Item)
    {
        if($Item["Col1"] == "valueDoo"){
            echo "<li>display relevant results</li>";                   
        }
    } 
echo "</ul>";
echo "<ul>";
foreach($Items as $Item)
    {
        if($Item["Col1"] == "valueHoo"){
            echo "<li>display relevant results</li>";                   
        }
    } 
echo "</ul>";
```

Is there a more efficient way? I'm still a newbie when it comes to php

Comment: I think you can directly use mysql_fetch_assoc($Data) in your foreach loop (you might have to change that to a while loop though). That way you can get rid of $Items = array(); and     $Items[] = $NewRow;

Comment: Additionally, in place of iterating through the whole $Items array thrice, maybe you can write 3 separate queries for the values of Col1 and filter the values at the query level itself.

Comment: What about $Items[$NewRow['Col1']][] = $NewRow; Then foreach($Items['valueFoo'] as $Item) . That way you still make one sql query.

Comment: There's not really anything wrong with this. I'd prefer to filter the results in php vs doing additional database queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I'd do is combine each check into one `foreach`, assigning the text to variables until the end, then echoing them as needed. Inside the `foreach` use a `switch` statement to avoid the multiple `if`s.

```
foreach($Items as $Item)
    {
      switch($Item["Col1"])
      {
         case 'valuefoo':
         $result_foo="<li>display relevant results</li>";  
         break;
         case 'valuedoo':
         $result_doo="<li>display relevant results</li>";  
         break;
         case 'valuehoo':
         $result_hoo="<li>display relevant results</li>";  
         break;
         default:
         // handle error if there is one
      }                
        }
    } 
echo "<ul>";
echo $result_foo;
echo "</ul>";

echo "<ul>";
echo $result_doo;
echo "</ul>";

echo "<ul>";
echo $result_hoo;
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: I wanted to combine the foreach loops but because it is nested and displayed within a list it would multiply the `<ul>` of each list

Comment: I didn't really want to just code it for you, but I did it anyway. Please see my edit.

Comment: I don't want to actually change the code now that it's been accepted, but where I have lines like `$result_foo="<li>display relevant results</li>";` It should probably be `$result_foo.="<li>display relevant results</li>";` notice the concatenation operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid your multiple `foreaches` by using this :

```
in_array(array("Col1" => "valueFoo"), $Items);
// ...
in_array(array("Col1" => "valueDoo"), $Items);
// ...
in_array(array("Col1" => "valueHoo"), $Items);
```

**edit**

If you want a better way, replace your whole code by this (see @Maximus2012 comment) :

```
while ($NewRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($Data)) {
    // Append all rows to an array
    if($NewRow["Col1"] == "valueFoo"){
        $foo = true;                 
    } else if($NewRow["Col1"] == "valueDoo"){
        $doo = true;
    } else if($NewRow["Col1"] == "valueHoo"){
        $hoo = true;
    }
} 

if($foo) {
    echo "<ul>display relevant results</ul>";
}

if($doo) {
    echo "<ul>display relevant results</ul>";
}

if($hoo) {
    echo "<ul>display relevant results</ul>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change how you've ordered the records fetched from the table. So that they are sequenced by `Col1` (first, and then other values second) and then you can check for changes in `Col1` to start a new `<ul>` group.

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Col1";
```

If your values for `Col1` are fixed values and can be mapped to functions. You could just dispatch calls to local functions of the same name. Otherwise you'll have to use a `switch` statement.

```
// create some functions to render each value type
function valueFoo()
{
    echo "<li>display relevant results</li>";
}

function valueHoo()
{
    echo "<li>display relevant results</li>";
}

function valueDoo()
{
    echo "<li>display relevant results</li>";
}

$last_col = false;
foreach($items as $item)
{
    $foo = $item["Col1"];
    if($last_col != $foo)
    {
        if($last_col !== false) echo "</ul>";
        echo "<ul>";
    }
    $foo();
    $last_col = $foo;
}
if($last_col !== false)
{
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
$ValuesAll = array();

foreach ($Items as $Item) {
    $ValuesAll[$Item['Col1']][] = '<li>' . $Item['Col2'] . '</li>';
}

foreach ($ValuesAll as $Value) {
    echo '<ul>' . implode('', $Value) . '</ul>';
}
```

This example will create UL for every unique `$Item['Col1']`. So, if you have Col1 `valueFoo`, `valueDoo`, and `valueHoo`, you will get 3 lists with `Col2`s for each of `Col1`.